# Deadline for updating product page for new iOS 11 App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, ios11

Apple will be rolling out new App Store on iOS 11. There are several changes including new `subtitle` and `promotional text` fields. App name will also be limited from 50 characters to 30 characters...etc.

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/product-page/

However, I couldn't find any information about the deadline. I assume Apple will force everyone to update their product page for the new App Store at some point.

Does anyone have any further information?

Answer (score 0):

There is no deadline, the `subtitle` and `promotional text` fields are optional. The placeholder text in iTunes Connect even says so:

[image: iTunes Connect]